# Как сделать, чтобы текст исчез по нажатию на окно?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlabel

Надо, чтобы при нажатии на окно в любую область, исчезал текст.

Как правильно это сделать?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, 
QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Widget(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

    self._old_pos = None

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addStretch()
    layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Закрыть окно", clicked=self.close))

    self.setLayout(layout)

    self.lbl = QLabel(self)
    self.lbl.setText("text")
    self.lbl.resize(30,30)

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self._old_pos = event.pos()

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self._old_pos = None

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if not self._old_pos:
        return

    delta = event.pos() - self._old_pos
    self.move(self.pos() + delta)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Опубликуйте ваш пример, который содержит окно и какой-то текст.

Comment: @S.Nick Изменил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте `self.lbl.clear()`  в методе `mousePressEvent`

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self._old_pos = event.pos()

        self.lbl.clear()                                          # <<---
```

Comment: а если это надо пихнуть после установки? То есть run и в конце надо прописать, чтобы по клику по окну текст и прогресс бар исчезал?

Comment: Сможете в этом случае помочь?

Comment: @Сергей я не понимаю о каком `run` и  `прогресс бар` вы говорите и что надо прописать. Вы задали вопрос, привели пример. Я ответил на вопрос согласно вашего примера. Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте НОВЫЙ вопрос, приведите пример и опишите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: event нельзя в другой деф прописать

Comment: я попробовал сделать тоже, только в определённый момент скрипта

Comment: через if event.

Comment: @Сергей Я ответил на вопрос согласно вашего примера. Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте НОВЫЙ вопрос, приведите пример и опишите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.